# Simple Nginx Proxy Pass and Regex

Tags: nginx

I want a simple nginx rule to pass the following example.

```
request http://myserver:8888/application/external/testUrl_1
```

redirect to

```
http://myglassfishserver:8080/application/external/testUrl_1
```

Then say I sent in

```
http://myserver:8888/application/external/testUrl_2
```

it would redirect to

```
http://myglassfishserver:8080/application/external/testUrl_2
```

I should also keep all post data if I were to send a http POST.

To me this seems like it should be simple.

I'm trying

```
                location ^/application/external {
                    proxy_pass  http://myglassfishserver:8080/$1;
                    allow all;
            }
```

I'm getting *1 access forbidden by rule, client: which I know is because it didn't match a rule. I've tried numerous combinations. What is it I've done wrong ? I'm guessing its the $1

Comment: Read nginx manual http://nginx.org/r/location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location /application/external/ {
    proxy_pass http://myglassfishserver:8080;
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks a mill. thought I was doing nothing wrong with the ^ and $1,